# Passing complicated argument patterns to a new command

Tags: macros, optional-arguments, xparse, changes

I am using the nice `changes` package. Which basically provides three commands `\added`, `\deleted` and `\replaced`. Because of the structure and the fact that the optional arguments it takes, I think it is possible to simplify its use. I followed the `xparse` package documentation to see if I could create a command that simplifies the call.

Below is a MWE. I was able to create two version of the command, one that `delete` and one that `replace` depending on the number of argument. But I ran quickly out of steam.

In summary here are the mappings I would like to achieve by defining a new command `\ME`:

- `\ME{deleted}` maps to `\deleted[id=Me]{deleted}`
- `\ME[added]` maps to `\added[id=Me]{added}` (or at least equivalent to `\ME[added]{}`)
- `\ME[replacing]{replaced}` maps to `\replaced[id=Me]{replacing}{replaced}`
- `\ME[comment]{deleted}` maps to `\deleted[id=Me, remark={comment}]{deleted}`
- `\ME[comment][added]` maps to `\added[id=Me,remark={comment}]{added}` (or equivalent to `\ME[comment][added]{}`)
- `\ME[comment][replacing]{replaced}` maps to `\replaced[id=Me, remark={comment}]{replacing}{replaced}`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{changes}
\usepackage{xparse}

\definechangesauthor[name={MyName},color=blue]{ME}

\DeclareDocumentCommand \ME { o m }{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}{
    \deleted[id=ME]{#2}}{
    \replaced[id=ME]{#1}{#2}
}
}


%\newcommand{\ME}[1]{\deleted[id=ME]{#1}} %ok

%\newcommand{\ME}[1][]{\added[id=ME]{#1}} % not working

\begin{document}

\added[id=ME,remark={added}]{added} 

\deleted[id=ME,remark={deleted}]{deleted}

\replaced[id=ME,remark={replaced}]{replacing}{replaced}

\ME{aaa}       % ok
\ME[aaa]{bbb}  % ok
\ME[aaa]{}     % ok

\ME{remark}[aaa]{} 

\end{document}
```

---

**EDIT:** Summary, so far. Thanks to @AxelBall and @ChristianHupfer I get this syntax, which is almost ideal (except for pure comments) with the implementation below:

```
\ME{addonly}

\ME{add}<deleted>

\ME<deleteonly>

\ME[addonlycommet]{addonly}

\ME[adddeletecomment]{add}<delete>

\ME[deleteonlycomment]<deleteonly>

text\ME[commentonly]
```

And finally the star variants, that add the `id` on the revision:

```
\ME*[deleteonlycomment]<deleteonly>
```

code:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\ME}{sogd<>}{
\IfBooleanTF#1{
\IfNoValueTF{#2}{\IfNoValueTF{#3}{\IfNoValueF{#4}{\deleted[id=ME]{#4}}}{\IfNoValueTF{#4}{\added[id=ME]{#3}}{\replaced[id=ME]{#3}{#4}}}}{\IfNoValueTF{#3}{\IfNoValueTF{#4}{\added[id=ME,remark={#2}]{}}{\deleted[id=ME, remark={#2}]{#4}}}{\IfNoValueTF{#4}{\added[id=ME,remark={#2}]{#3}}{\replaced[id=ME, remark={#2}]{#3}{#4}}}}
}{
\IfNoValueTF{#2}{\IfNoValueTF{#3}{\IfNoValueF{#4}{\deleted{#4}}}{\IfNoValueTF{#4}{\added{#3}}{\replaced{#3}{#4}}}}{\IfNoValueTF{#3}{\IfNoValueTF{#4}{\added[remark={#2}]{}}{\deleted[remark={#2}]{#4}}}{\IfNoValueTF{#4}{\added[remark={#2}]{#3}}{\replaced[remark={#2}]{#3}{#4}}}}
}
}
```

Comment: How should the command decide in the case `\Me[something]{real arg}` if something is the designed for the 2nd opt or as the 1st opt. You need another syntax, in my point of view. In addition, the omittance of `{}` as mandatory argument is very difficult to achieve.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, good point. I think adding an empty argument would be a work around `\Me[comment]{added}{}` or `\Me[][replacing]{replaced}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here we define a command `\ME` that takes three optional arguments:

```
\ME[optional comment]<deleted content>(added content)
```

Either or both of `<deleted>` and `(added)` must be given or the command does nothing (but no error/warning is raised).

(**EDITED** to correct replacing behaviour.)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{changes}
\usepackage{xparse}

\definechangesauthor[name={MyName},color=blue]{ME}

\NewDocumentCommand{\ME}{od<>d()}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}{%
    \IfNoValueTF{#2}{%
      \IfNoValueF{#3}{%
        % (#3)
        \added[id=ME]{#3}%
      }%
    }{%
      \IfNoValueTF{#3}{%
        % <#2>
        \deleted[id=ME]{#2}%
      }{% <#2>(#3)
        \replaced[id=ME]{#3}{#2}%
      }%
    }%
  }{%
    \IfNoValueTF{#2}{%
      \IfNoValueF{#3}{%
        % [#1](#3)
        \added[id=ME,remark={#1}]{#3}%
      }%
    }{%
      \IfNoValueTF{#3}{%
        % [#1]<#2>
        \deleted[id=ME, remark={#1}]{#2}%
      }{% [#1]<#2>(#3)
        \replaced[id=ME, remark={#1}]{#3}{#2}%
      }%
    }%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
\deleted[id=ME]{deleted} 
& \ME<deleted> \\
\added[id=ME]{added}
& \ME(added) \\
\replaced[id=ME]{replacing}{replaced}
& \ME<replaced>(replacing)\\
\deleted[id=ME, remark={comment}]{deleted}
& \ME[comment]<deleted> \\
\added[id=ME,remark={comment}]{added}
& \ME[comment](added)\\
\replaced[id=ME, remark={comment}]{replacing}{replaced}
& \ME[comment]<replaced>(replacing)\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output from first code sample]

In case you are concerned about using parentheses, don't be. `xparse` copes perfectly well if you use balanced parentheses inside the third argument; if you want an unbalanced one, wrap it in braces: `\ME(like {(} this)`.

If you really want to use braces for the last argument, you can can use the `g` specifier:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\ME}{od<>g}{...}
```

---

**EDIT**

Okay, this should do what you want:

```
\documentclass[border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{changes}
\usepackage{xparse}

\definechangesauthor[name={MyName},color=blue]{ME}

\NewDocumentCommand{\ME}{ogd<>}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}{%
    \IfNoValueTF{#2}{%
      \IfNoValueF{#3}{%
        % <#3>
        \deleted[id=ME]{#3}%
      }%
    }{%
      \IfNoValueTF{#3}{%
        % {#2}
        \added[id=ME]{#2}%
      }{% {#2}<#3>
        \replaced[id=ME]{#2}{#3}%
      }%
    }%
  }{%
    \IfNoValueTF{#2}{%
      \IfNoValueTF{#3}{%
        % [1]
        \added[id=ME,remark={#1}]{}%
      }{% [#1]<#3>
        \deleted[id=ME, remark={#1}]{#3}%
      }%
    }{%
      \IfNoValueTF{#3}{%
        % [#1]{#2}
        \added[id=ME,remark={#1}]{#2}%
      }{% [#1]{#2}<#3>
        \replaced[id=ME, remark={#1}]{#2}{#3}%
      }%
    }%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
\verb|\ME<deleted>|
& \ME<deleted> \\
\verb|\ME{added}|
& \ME{added} \\
\verb|\ME{added}<deleted>|
& \ME{added}<deleted>\\
\verb|\ME[comment]|
& \ME[comment]\\
\verb|\ME[comment]<deleted>|
& \ME[comment]<deleted> \\
\verb|\ME[comment]{added}|
& \ME[comment]{added}\\
\verb|\ME[comment]{added}<deleted>|
& \ME[comment]{added}<deleted>\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: Output from second code sample]

Comment: Great thanks something like this should be optional in `changes`, it simplifies writing changes a lot. Three things 1) I would like to have braces `{...}` for the second (added text) argument (currently `<...>`) not the third 2) is it possible to add `\ME[comment]` for a pure comment (translated to `\added[remark={comment}]{}` (or `\ME[comment]{}` if that is impossible) 3) in your code there is an inconsistency where the `added` and `deleted` are reversed when they are alone relative to the combined case` (It took me a while to get it right)

Comment: @alfC: I have edited my answer to address all three points.

Comment: Thanks, I added a `star` variant to the command in the edit to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

This is uses in fact three optional arguments:

```
\ME[operation driver]<operation argument>[operation comment]
```

Any of them can be omitted, in this case nothing would happen.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{changes}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{xparse}

\definechangesauthor[name={MyName},color=blue]{ME}

\DeclareDocumentCommand \MEOrig{ o m }{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}{
    \deleted[id=ME]{#2}}{
    \replaced[id=ME]{#1}{#2}
}
}



\DeclareDocumentCommand{\ME}{oD<>{}o}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}{%
    \IfValueTF{#3}{%
      \deleted[id=ME,remark={#3}]{#2}%
    }{%
      \deleted[id=ME]{#2}%
    }%  
  }{%
    \IfStrEq{#1}{added}{%
      \IfValueTF{#2}{%
        \IfValueTF{#3}{%
          \added[id=ME,remark={#3}]{#2}%
        }{%
          \added[id=ME]{#2}%
        }%
      }{%
        \IfValueTF{#3}{%
          \added[id=ME,remark={#3}]{}%
        }{%
          \added[id=ME]{}%
        }%
      }%
    }{% 
      \IfStrEq{#1}{replacing}{%
        \IfValueTF{#3}{%
          \replaced[id=ME,remark={#3}]{replacing}{#2}%
        }{%
          \replaced[id=ME]{replacing}{#2}%
        }%
      }{%
        % Do nothing in here
      }%      
    }% End of IfStrEq{#1}{added}
  }% End of IfNoValueTF{#1}
}







\begin{document}



\added[id=ME,remark={added}]{added} 

\deleted[id=ME,remark={deleted}]{deleted}

\replaced[id=ME,remark={replaced}]{replacing}{replaced}

\ME<aaa>       % ok
\ME[aaa]<bbb>  % ok
\ME[aaa]     % ok

\ME<remark>[aaa]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I am little bit in a hurry, so I can not test any code. It's a proposition, not a full solution yet

Comment: Awesome, I didn't know that `<>` can also be used, perhaps in the light of it remarks can always go in `<>`, added/replacing in `[]` and deleted in `{}`.

Comment: `D` is the `delimited` argument version (there is also `d`) which allows for basically any token (but not [] or {}, as far as I know). I am still thinking, if a key-value approach would not be even better, as wrapper around the different commands

Comment: A key/value approach is something that I also wanted to avoid to make changes as short as possible, and in particular not including any word that would make reading more difficult. That is why I wanted something that avoided the `remark=` keyword.

Comment: I can't manage to use some of the combinations, For example `\ME<deleted> 

\ME[remark deleted]<deleted> 

\ME[remark] 

\ME<deleted>[remark deleted]`. Out of the four commands, only 2 produce output.

Comment: @alfC: Ah yes, I almost forgot about this. I should review it, but as far as I remember I thought that your design of the features of this command is too complicated.

Comment: I agree, it is just that keeping revision `change` code very compact would be good feature to have. I don't know if it is possible but a design with `\ME[optional remark]<optional delete>{optional add}` perhaps is feasible?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer `d` works for (almost) any pair of token bar `{}`. In particular, `o` is just a shortcut for `d[]`!

Comment: @JosephWright: Huh?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer In your earlier comment you say '`D` is the delimited argument version (there is also `d`) which allows for basically any token (but not `[]` or `{}`, as far as I know).' I was just pointing out that `d[]` or `D[]` is entirely valid and is the way that `o`/`O` is actually implemented.

Comment: @JosephWright: Ah, ok. I misunderstand perhaps some statement in the manual, that `[]` or `{}` wouldn't be allowed. I know that `o`/`O` falls back internally to `D`