# How to define a command that defines another command?

Tags: macros, xparse

I have a command defined with `xparse` that looks like this:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\ME}{sogd<>}{\added[id=ME,remark={#1}]{#2}}
```

(for the full code see [Passing complicated argument patterns to a new command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/240968/passing-complicated-argument-patterns-to-a-new-command/247589?noredirect=1#comment589584_247589))

Now, I want this to be defined *through* another command, something like

```
\newcommand{\definerevision}[1]{
    \NewDocumentCommand{\#1}{gg}{\added[id=#1,remark={??#1}]{??#2}}
}
```

(`??` means "what to put here?")

That is `\definerevision{INITIAL}` expands to define the command `\NewDocumentCommand{\INITIAL}{gg}{\added[id=INITIAL,remark={#1}]{#2}}` (e.g. in the header)

There are two potential problems, the first is to expand `\#1` and the second is that the argument #1 has to be distinguished between the top level command or the nested command (how to distinguish).

**Is there a way to define a command through another command using `\newcommand` or `\xparse`?**

Comment: Yes, there is ... For the inner command you need ##1 instead #1, etc, and the definition requires some more to-do... I'll try to answer it

Comment: I am sure, you meant `remark=##2`, since `##1` is the starred optional argument.

Comment: I tried to simplify the code for this question so I put simply `...{gg}{ ... #1 ... #2}`. Also I put `??` to know what to put there.

Comment: Changed my solution to your `{gg}` macro

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Defining a command within another command requires to use the `\csname #1 \endcsname` approach for the `\NewDocumentCommand` (or `\newcommand` as well) (assuming #1 is the name of the new command, as argument of the outer command), preceeded by `\expandafter`

If a command is defined within another one, all parameter arguments characters `#` have to be doubled, it i.e. `##1`, `##2`, etc.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newcommand{\added}[1]{%
\Large%
\textbf{Arg was #1}%
}

\newcommand{\definerevision}[1]{%
  \expandafter\NewDocumentCommand\csname #1\endcsname{gg}{\added[id=#1,remark={##1}]{##2}}%
}


\definerevision{MOE}  

\definerevision{LARRY}  

\definerevision{CURLY}  
\begin{document}

\MOE{Added}{only this}

\LARRY{Added}{other more important stuff}

\CURLY{Screwed}{up the whole thing}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Awesome. It is important not to put `{}` around `\csname #1\endcsname` (I did that mistake first)

Comment: `\expandafter\NewDocumentCommand{\csname....}` would try to expand `{` which is useless here... and believe me, I did that mistake too (some months ago ;-))